# Using permutations to find the next biggest number

Tags: python, python-3.x, permutation

> Create a function that takes a positive integer and returns the next bigger number that can be formed by rearranging its digits.

To accomplish this I used the following code:

Logic used:

1. Write a  script do all the permutations of the number  e.g. 123 -> 132,321,231,...
2. select the largest number from the possible combinations
3. if that number is bigger than original number provided it returns that number - if not it returns -1.

**Code Block:**

```
import itertools
def next_bigger(n):
    # [int(x) for x in str(n)] ex: convert 123 to array [1,2,3]
    # list(set(itertools.permutations... gives you a list of permutation e.g. [[1,3,2],[3,2,1],[2,3,1],...]
    # [int(''.join(map(str,x))) for x in ...  converts each permuted list into a number e.g. convert [2,3,1] -> 231
    # for num in sorted(...if num>n: --> if 321 is bigger than 123, return it
    
     for num in sorted([int(''.join(map(str,x))) for x in list(set(itertools.permutations([int(x) for x in str(n)])))]):
        if num>n:
            return num
        else:
            return -1
```

Expected Output:

```
nextBigger(num: 12)   // returns 21
nextBigger(num: 513)  // returns 531
nextBigger(num: 2017) // returns 2071
nextBigger(num: 9)   // returns nil
nextBigger(num: 111) // returns nil
nextBigger(num: 531) // returns nil
```

Actual Output: `Test results fail`

Solution Attempt#2:

```
import itertools
def next_bigger(n):
    # [int(x) for x in str(n)] ex: convert 123 to array [1,2,3]
    # list(set(itertools.permutations... gives you a list of permutation e.g. [[1,3,2],[3,2,1],[2,3,1],...]
    # [int(''.join(map(str,x))) for x in ...  converts each permuted list into a number e.g. convert [2,3,1] -> 231
    # for num in sorted(...if num>n: --> if 321 is bigger than 123, return it
    
    a = []
    results = 0
    for num in sorted([int(''.join(map(str,x))) for x in list(set(itertools.permutations([int(x) for x in str(n)])))]):
        if num>n:
            a.append(num)
    results = a[0]
            
    return results
```

Expected output: Passes all tests cases except for long numbers

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: We're looking for the *next larger* permutation, not the *largest* permutation. (Also, going through *every* permutation is crazy slow.)

Comment: What would be the best approach to it then? The logic picks the number which is larger than the number inputted

Comment: Someone should sanity check me, but it seems like the algorithm to use is to take the least significant digit, swap it with the first more significant digit with a lower magnitude, then sort all the digits below that point. So for `98176543` you'd start with `3`, swap it with `1` (the first smaller digit to the left) to get `98376541`, then sort all digits to the right of the new `3` location, getting `98314567` as the next larger permutation. Like I said, that's first thought, and it's late, so I might be making an elementary mistake. If it works, it's infinitely faster than your approach.

Comment: On checking, it needs some work (if the least significant digit is smaller than all other digits, try again with the second least significant digit and so on).

Answer (score 1):

The title says 'using permutations', but you don't need to use permutations for this.

The order of the tuples [itertools.permutations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) emitted is defined; but unfortunately it will not always produce digits that when combined are in increasing order. Also calculating all permutations will take an extremely long time if the number of digits is very large.

To rephrase the question: for any given `N`, what is the smallest number (`N2`) such that:

1. `0 <= N < N2`, and
2. The number of times each digit appears in `N` and `N2` are the same

(if `N2` doesn't exist, return `None`)

We could start from `N` and do `N+=1` until condition 2 is satisfied, or until condition 2 can no longer be satisfied because the total number of digits in `N` increased. (An `int` in Python 3 has no defined limit for how big it can get, so we would not get an overflow.) This is still (on average) extremely slow if `N` is very large, however it will in theory eventually return.

Here is how I would solve this:

```py
def main(N):
    n=list(map(int,str(N)))
    for i_r in reversed(range(len(n))):
        for i_l in reversed(range(i_r)):
            if n[i_l]<n[i_r]:
                t_l=n[i_l]
                t_r=n[i_r]
                n[i_l]=t_r
                n[i_r]=t_l
                return int(''.join(map(str,n)))
    return None
```

First convert `N` into a list of digits (while preserving the order). This will make `N` easier to work on.

Make 2 markers `i_l` and `i_r`. `i_l` and `i_r` will always be on the left and right respectively. They will start on the least significant (i.e. right) side of `N`.

They will go through `N` like this for example:

```
4321    4321    4321    4321    4321    4321
  lr     l r    l  r     lr     l r     lr
```

When `i_l < i_r`, swap those digits to make a bigger number, which satisfies condition 1. Since `i_l` and `i_r` start from the least significant side of `N`, that new number is the smallest number that satisfies condition 2. If that number doesn't exist, the function returns `None`.

(The `return None` is actually unnecessary, as functions by default return `None`, however explicitly stating it makes it more clear that this is the intended behavior.)

With this solution, even if `N` is 10000 digits, the function will return in a reasonable amount of time.

Answer (score 0):

You need the next biggest number, but currently you pick `any` permutation-number greater than the input-number. `You should be the picking the minimum among such numbers`

Also notice, for example for input `9` or `111`; there are no other permutations; so you might just want to return the `next biggest-permutation or None`.

You might consider modifying to this:

```
import itertools
def next_bigger(n):
    # [int(x) for x in str(n)] ex: convert 123 to array [1,2,3]
    # list(set(itertools.permutations... gives you a list of permutation e.g. [[1,3,2],[3,2,1],[2,3,1],...]
    # [int(''.join(map(str,x))) for x in ...  converts each permuted list into a number e.g. convert [2,3,1] -> 231
    # for num in sorted(...if num>n: --> if 321 is bigger than 123, return it
    
     minval = -1
     for num in sorted([int(''.join(map(str,x))) for x in list(set(itertools.permutations([int(x) for x in str(n)])))]):
        if num>n:
            if minval == -1 or minval > num:
                minval = n
     return minval
```

Appropriate test-cases:

```
nextBigger(num: 1176) //should return 1617
```

Comment: @ApplicationTeam please elaborate

Comment: Your code did not clear any test cases and failed for some reason. However I get the logic your trying to apply and came up with the logic of appending numbers to an empty list as long as they are greater than the number entered. Once that is done, I returned the value at the first position in the list. The test case passed but on submission, it just kept executing

Comment: It would fail on bigger number example: 492538761
492561378