# Optimized or best way to find an immediate number of a number of same digits

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization, logic

So I have a number like 123 the immediate number with same digits is 132. Consider another example, number is 1238 the next immediate number is 1283. So for this logic I already implemented a code

```
def findnext(n):
    ns=list(map(int,str(n)))
    for i in reversed(range(len(ns))):
        if i == 0: return n
        if ns[i] > ns[i-1] :
            break        
    left,right=ns[:i],ns[i:]
    for k in reversed(range(len(right))):
        if right[k]>left[-1]:
           right[k],left[-1]=left[-1],right[k]
           break
    return int("".join(map(str,(left+sorted(right)))))
n=int(input())
print(findnext(n))
```

I need a logic which is more optimized or more reduced code without using itertools. Please Help me!! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is https://stackoverflow.com/a/64889338 what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can to this without any for loops or library function.  The strategy is as follows:

- Find the position of the last increasing sequence of 2 digits (`pivot`)
- The first of these two digits will be replaced by a higher digit
- and the rest will be in sorted order of remaining digits (`suffix`)
- The higher digit to use is the smallest one in the remaining digits that is larger than the one we're replacing (`digit`)

Here's how it could be implemented:

```
def nextPerm(N):
    sN     = list(str(N))
    incPos = [i for i,d in enumerate(sN[:-1]) if d<sN[i+1]]
    if not incPos: return None
    pivot  = incPos[-1]
    suffix = sN[pivot:]
    digit  = min(d for d in suffix if d>sN[pivot])
    suffix.remove(digit)
    sN[pivot:] = [digit]+suffix[::-1]
    return int("".join(sN))
```

**output:**

```
n = 1234
while n:
    print(n)
    n = nextPerm(n)

1234
1243
1324
1342
1423
1432
2134
2143
2314
2341
2413
2431
3124
3142
3214
3241
3412
3421
4123
4132
4213
4231
4312
4321
```

It is also possible to do this without converting to strings:

```
def nextPerm(N):
    suffix = []
    while N: 
        N,digit = divmod(N,10)
        suffix.append(digit)
        if len(suffix)>1 and digit<suffix[-2]:
            break
    else: return
    suffix = sorted(suffix)
    swap   = min(s for s in suffix if s>digit)
    suffix.remove(swap)
    for d in [swap]+suffix: N = N*10 + d
    return N
```

It uses the same strategy but breaks down the number using divisions operations instead of building a list of string digits.

Answer (score 0):

This is less of a python question and moreso a logic question.

The way I understood your question correctly you need to use the same digits and find the closest number to that. Logically that means most of the time you want to switch the two last digits. But if I did that the closest to your example of `1238` is `1283`, with the distance being `1283-1238=45` instead of `1328-1238=90, or did I miss some sort of rule?
Can the distance be both ways or only one?

When I am sure of the rules I (and others) can probably help more.